# If velocity is a function of position and position is function of time, is velocity a function of time as well?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was reading through Lagrangian Mechanics and noticed this sort of question popping up everywhere. To illustrate, the 3d x coordinate was considered to be a function of X, Y (degrees of freedom). Now in the differentiating mess, the authors considered both x and X as functions of time. But I thought x was a function of X and hence the confusion.

Comment: Yes, velocity can be considered as a function of position rather than as a function of time.

Comment: @G.Smith Stated this way I am afraid that there could be some problem with counting the number of independent degrees of freedom.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're getting at, but velocity is not in general a function of position, because an object can have two different velocities at the same position, if it returns to the same point at two times.

Comment: @ Ben Crowell Thanks for making that point. Lemme edit the question

Comment: Maybe you could show the math you are talking about?

Comment: Here is a simple kinematics question where velocity is treated as a function of position: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489934/kinematics-problem-basic Ben Crowell is correct that doing this does not make sense for *general* motion, but there are many problems where it is a perfectly sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If Lagrangian is written as $L=L(x(t),v(t),t)$, $L$ is time-dependent explicity through $t$ and implicitely through $x$ and $v$. 
If $L=L(x(t),v(t))$, then $L$ is not explicitly dependent on time but implicitly dependent on time through $x$ and $v$. This means $L$ can change if and only if $x$ and $v$ changes with time and can't change with time without a change in $x$ and $v$.

Same explanation goes for all the functions depending explicitly and implicitly on time.